# How can I test my website on a MS Edge web browser, if I do not have it installed?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have windows 7 and I have these 3 browsers installed:-

1. Firefox Quantum version 60
2. IE 11.
3. chrome 66.

Now I want to test how my website will look like on MS Edge. But I am not sure what I need to do. so I have these 3 questions:-

1. Can I install MS Edge and keep IE 11? If so will I have 2 browsers types?.
2. Are there any MS Edge simulators, I can use for testing?
3. Inside IE11 F12 tools, I can find MS edge under simulators, as follows:-
   [image: Screenshot of Edge emulation via IE11] 
   So will choosing this option mimic MS Edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible but you need to run a virtual machine. Microsoft made a web page where you can download an image containing Windows 10 with the last version of Edge. Here is where you can get : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

[image: MSEDGE]

There is also a paid solution, you can sign up to https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-microsoft-edge-browser#live-cloud where there is plenty of web browser you can test.

Comment: Ok great will download it but it might take a while. but since I have windows 7, so from the "Virtual Machine" i will chose "MSedge on win10(x64) stable", but under Platform which one i need to use? now i already have VMware workstation installed on my PC

Comment: If you have VMware workstation choose VMware (Windows, Mac). It depends of which virtual software you use. You will need to unzip in a particular folder and with VMware you will point to that folder. When you launch you will have a trial of 90 days before expiration. It's a simple windows 10 installation with Edge on it.

Comment: one question i have .. now if i install the VMware will i be able to renew it after 90 days?

Comment: I think if you redownload and reinstall a new image you sould be ready to go for an another 90 days. But not tested.

Comment: ok thanks for the info... but generally speaking (although it might not be related to the original question ), is the latest version of Firefox and latest version of chrome should have the same specification as in MS Edge ? i mean if something is working on Firefox and chrome latest versions then it should work on MS Edge.. or this is not the case?

Comment: The specification would be very close but there will be always some little differencies. In last version of those browser it's very similar.

Comment: Now i download the VM, but when i try to run it inside vmware workstation version 9 i got this error `*****\MSEdge.Win10.VMWare\MSEdge - Win10.vmx" was created by a VMware product that is incompatible with this version of VMware Workstation and cannot be used.`

Comment: and also i edit the .vmx file in note pad and i change the version from 12 to 9 .. but when i try to run the vm inside vmware workstation it will start for a while then it will close.

Comment: Maybe try to upgrade your VMware workstation to the latest version or install Virtualbox (it's free), it's with Virtualbox I tested.